# Asp.net MultiView /check ActiveViewIndex With Javascript Or jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, null, multiview, activeview

Why does the below alert always show me null?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Keyup._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

<%--    <script src="JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                document.onkeyup = onkeyupOfDocument;

                function onkeyupOfDocument(evt) {
                    //var MultiView = $("*[id$='TextBox1']"); 
                    var MultiView = document.getElementById("MultiView1");
                    alert(MultiView);
                }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After solving null problem how can I check `ActiveViewIndex` with JavaScript or jQuery?

It seems

```
if(MultiView.ActiveViewIndex == 0)
```

is not true!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after our page is completely loaded into the browser & viewing the source code , we can say it's not possible to CHANGE **(Not CHECK)** the ActiveViewIndex of Regular MultiView In asp.net with only javascrip or jquery.
because there is no element out there with MultiView1 id -> just a div Existed.

we only can check the ActiveViewIndex of MultiView1 as Nathan has answered by below code :

```
var activeViewIndex = <%=MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex %>;
```

plz see the below link for more information (latest post):
[MultiView Is A reach Element](http://forums.asp.net/t/1323392.aspx/1)
therefore the below code has no meaning :

```
var MultiView = document.getElementById("<%=MultiView1.ClientID %>");
```

if you want to **CHANGE** (Not Check) the ActiveViewIndex in client side there is a trick -> plz look at the below codes :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected void butSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = int.Parse(HiddenField1.Value);
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Demo</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/ecmascript">
    function OnClientClick( ServerControID,IndexControlID, Index){
        var objDemo = document.getElementById(ServerControID);
        if(objDemo){
            document.getElementById(IndexControlID).value = Index;
            objDemo.click();                        
        }        
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                    <span style="color: #ff0000; background-color: #33ccff"><strong>Hi, I am View 1</strong></span></asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                    <strong><span style="color: background; background-color: #99ff00">Hi, I am View 2</span></strong></asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView></div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        <input id="btnShow1" type="button" value="Show View 1" onclick="OnClientClick('butSubmit','HiddenField1','0')" />
        <input id="btnShow2" type="button" value="Show View 2" onclick="OnClientClick('butSubmit','HiddenField1','1')" />
        <div style="display: none">
            <asp:Button ID="butSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="butSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the source code of the upper codes after the page is loaded in ie 9 :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><title>
    Demo
</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/ecmascript">

        function OnClientClick(ServerControID, IndexControlID, Index) {
            var objDemo = document.getElementById(ServerControID);
            if (objDemo) {
                document.getElementById(IndexControlID).value = Index;
                objDemo.click();
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="WebForm3.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUIODMxNDI3MTNkGAEFCk11bHRpVmlldzEPD2RmZJjYXp6H2AsOwVGwRlIRlk0x9agdyp/Kg++cmPNXKpTg" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKrwZG1BAKQo8KrDX7rF3izcHDs+E9bwpx3GnVGoIZVi2Gpv0IOOu9xXNMo" />
</div>
        <div>

                    <span style="color: #ff0000; background-color: #33ccff"><strong>Hi, I am View 1</strong></span></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="HiddenField1" id="HiddenField1" value="1" />
        <input id="btnShow1" type="button" value="Show View 1" onclick="OnClientClick('butSubmit','HiddenField1','0')" />
        <input id="btnShow2" type="button" value="Show View 2" onclick="OnClientClick('butSubmit','HiddenField1','1')" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: during the giving an answer to this question somebody voted me down because of previous writing / i was editing my answer / plz vote me up / it's not fair ...

Comment: @LostLord: Don't worry about the downvote, the important part is that you got your answer.  It would certainly make the answer more readable to exclude all the parts you don't need to give the answer however.

Comment: dear @NickLarsen : i removed acception of my answer till i certain that we can not change the ActiveViewIndex With **Only JavaScript** and without any help from server side code against upper answer ! i am in doubt becouse of Nathan comments.we need more people about this issue.

Comment: @LostLord, my comments don't indicate that this can be done without server-side interaction - in fact, it can't - your question asks how  to GET the active view on the client (which is doable) - you dont' state that you needed to CHANGE the view.  That make sense?  So, in summary - if your question is "how can I change the active view with javascript?", then the answer is "only by making a call back to the server".

Comment: @Nathan i checked your codes again and i really apologize for my insistence / document.getElementById("<%=MultiView1.ClientID %>"); returned null & activeViewIndex = <%=MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex %>; worked perfect / i told you this code had error because in vs 2010 it had a little green mark under it / however your answer is related to my Q and my answer is another issue

Comment: @LostLord no problem - glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var MultiView = document.getElementById("MultiView1");
```

to

```
var MultiView = document.getElementById("<%=MultiView1.ClientID %>");
```

the reason the alert is always null is that there is no element on the **client-side** called MultiView1: that's the **server-side** id of the control.

to get the active view index to the client-side, use this:

```
var activeViewIndex = <%=MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex %>;
```

Comment: thanks for answer to this question! just a moment / i am testing it

Comment: you are wrong bro - i test your codes like this after adding a ScriptManager ->         function pageLoad() {
            var MultiView = document.getElementById("<%=MultiView1.ClientID %>");
            alert(MultiView);
        } still returns null... (we use ClientID because of master and content pages - but here there is no MultiView after render , just a div) plz give us an explain!!!

Comment: What does document.getElementById("<%=MultiView1.ClientID %>"); render as?

Comment: the code i've listed is correct under normal circumstances, it sounds like there's something very wrong with your multiview / server-side.

Comment: Does your multiview render at all?  please view-source in your browser and add it to the question.

Comment: it seems there is no element with MultiView1 id after page is loaded -> we only have a div element. - just a moment - i am adding the source code...

Comment: Ok, try creating a separate aspx page with just a multiview in it - if that works (ie displays), then there's some code on your current page that is messing up your multiview1.  If it doesn't then... dunno

Comment: Have to log out now I'm afraid - will check back later today.