# Multiview in javascript

Tags: asp.net

I Have 3 views in my multiview control. I want to change the activeviewindex of the multiview on client side using javascript. I cant do it. Help will be appreciated.
my code is:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="multiviewContainer" CssClass="multiviewContainer">
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            View 0
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            View 1
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
            View 2
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View4" runat="server">
            View 3
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: [check this link] :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300628/asp-net-multiview-check-activeviewindex-with-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MultiView is a server-side control and not meant to be modified client-side, so even if it's technically possible to change the active index client-side, you probably shouldn't. So I don't think anyone is going to provide any sort of "good" answer for this question. Why not use jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ChangeActiveIndex(index) {
        $('div').hide(); // change this selector to be more specific
        $('#div' + index).show();
    }

</script>

<div id="div1">View 1</div>
<div id="div2">View 2</div>
<div id="div3">View 3</div>

<span onclick="ChangeActiveIndex(1);">Show View 1</span>
<span onclick="ChangeActiveIndex(2);">Show View 2</span>
<span onclick="ChangeActiveIndex(3);">Show View 3</span>
```

You can also modify them in your code behind if needed:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">View 1</div>

div1.Attributes.Add("class", "make-a-class-display:none-or-display:inline")
```